# Display non-zoomable web page on Android at native resolution?

Tags: android, html

I've added the following to a web page to make it non-zoomable on mobile devices and to *try* to make is display at native resolution:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
```

However when viewing that on my Samsung Galaxy S and printing out `screen.width` from JavaScript it gives 320 in portrait orientation and 533 in landscape orientation.  How can I get it to use the the native resolution of 480×800, or is that just not possible?

I'd like to do this so that the quality of images isn't degraded by being displayed at a zoom of 1.5 (initially pixelated then having a smoothing filter applied).

Comment: I've found some useful info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#A_pixel_is_not_a_pixel).  So `device-width` is set to whatever gives 96 dpi "CSS pixels" rather than the number of physical pixels on the device, and the correct way to avoid image degradation would be to display them zoomed out (i.e. smaller width/height than their actual size) to compensate for the automatic zooming in on higher resolution screens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This viewport syntax implements the desired behavior:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width" />
```

By specifying the target density to match the native density of the display, it renders at native resolution (1pixel=1pixel) and you don't see smoothing or other artifacts.

Works for me on Samsung Galaxy S, but YMMV on other devices and Android/Browser versions.

See below for more info:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#ViewportDensity

Answer (score 0):

I think if you fixe the maximum (and minium) scale to the inital scale like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the meta  viewport is in place, then you can still have a zoomed-out page with tiny texts if anything in the html/css of the page lets the mobile browser think it should be displaying something wide. Even an ordinary `<p>tag with enough text inside</p>` can make the whole page zoom out. One way of rounding up the culprits is to make changes to you css, slashing stuff out using `{ display: none }` until you find the exact section that is causing the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Tip for MGWT users:
MGWTSettings.ViewPort will not set "target-densitydpi" correctly.
This must be in your html file.